# How to avoid adding double start of token in TrOCR finetune model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

**Describe the bug**
The model I am using (TrOCR Model):

The problem arises when using:

- [x] the official example scripts: done by the nice tutorial  [(fine_tune)](https://github.com/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/TrOCR/Fine_tune_TrOCR_on_IAM_Handwriting_Database_using_Seq2SeqTrainer.ipynb) @NielsRogge
- [x] my own modified scripts: (as the script below )

```
processor = TrOCRProcessor.from_pretrained("microsoft/trocr-large-handwritten")

class Dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root_dir, df, processor, max_target_length=128):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.df = df
        self.processor = processor
        self.max_target_length = max_target_length

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.df)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # get file name + text 
        file_name = self.df['file_name'][idx]
        text = self.df['text'][idx]
        # prepare image (i.e. resize + normalize)
        image = Image.open(self.root_dir + file_name).convert("RGB")
        pixel_values = self.processor(image, return_tensors="pt").pixel_values
        # add labels (input_ids) by encoding the text
        labels = self.processor.tokenizer(text, 
                                          padding="max_length",
                                                         max_length=self.max_target_length).input_ids
        # important: make sure that PAD tokens are ignored by the loss function
        labels = [label if label != self.processor.tokenizer.pad_token_id else -100 for label in labels]
        # encoding  
        return {"pixel_values": pixel_values.squeeze(), "labels": torch.tensor(labels)}

model = VisionEncoderDecoderModel.from_pretrained("microsoft/trocr-large-handwritten")
model.config.decoder_start_token_id = processor.tokenizer.cls_token_id
model.config.pad_token_id = processor.tokenizer.pad_token_id
model.config.vocab_size = model.config.decoder.vocab_size

model.config.eos_token_id = processor.tokenizer.sep_token_id


# python3 train.py path/to/labels  path/to/images/
```

- Platform: Linux  Ubuntu  distribution  [GCC 9.4.0] on Linux
- PyTorch version (GPU?):  0.8.2+cu110
- transformers: 4.22.2
- Python version:3.8.10

A clear and concise description of what the bug is.
To **Reproduce** Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. After training the model or during the training phase  when evaluating metrics calculate I see the model added the double start of token `<s><s>` or ids `[0,0, ......,2,1,1, 1 ]`
2. here is an example during the `training` phase the show generated tokens in compute_metrics
   Input predictions: `[[0,0,506,4422,8046,2,1,1,1,1,1]]`
   Input references: `[[0,597,2747 ...,1,1,1]]`
3. Other examples during `testing` models [[image]]

**Expected behavior** A clear and concise description of what you expected to happen.
In 2 reproduced problems:
I am expecting during training Input predictions: `[[,0,,506,4422,8046,2,1,1,1,1,1 ]]`

In addition during the testing phase:  generated text without double 
`tensor([[0,11867,405,22379,1277,..........,368,2]])`

`<s>ennyit erről, tőlem fényképezz amennyit akarsz, a véleményem akkor</s>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from passed token ids. I am adding  start token from tokenizer  +  another start token from the TrOCR model so the duplication happens. the solution is super easy by just skipping  start token coming from the tokenizer  by using `labels = labels[1:]`

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # get file name + text 
        file_name = self.df['file_name'][idx]
        text = self.df['text'][idx]
        # prepare image (i.e. resize + normalize)
        image = Image.open(self.root_dir + file_name).convert("RGB")
        pixel_values = self.processor(image, return_tensors="pt").pixel_values
        # add labels (input_ids) by encoding the text
        labels = self.processor.tokenizer(text, 
                                          padding="max_length",
                                                                                    max_length=self.max_target_length).input_ids
        # important: make sure that PAD tokens are ignored by the loss function
        labels = [label if label != self.processor.tokenizer.pad_token_id else -100 for label in labels]
        # encoding
        labels = labels[1:]   
        return {"pixel_values": pixel_values.squeeze(), "labels": torch.tensor(labels)}
```